# How to Format QImage to BAYER color (GRBG)?

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is the code piece that I wrote for streaming the camera captures:

```
VideoCapture cap;

VideoStreamer::VideoStreamer()
{
    connect(&tUpdate,&QTimer::timeout,this,&VideoStreamer::streamVideo);    
}

VideoStreamer::~VideoStreamer()
{
    cap.release();
    tUpdate.stop();
}
 
void VideoStreamer::streamVideo()
{
    //Capture frame by frame
    cap>>frame;
    QImage imgOriginal = QImage(frame.data,frame.cols,frame.rows,QImage::Format_RGB32).rgbSwapped();
}

void VideoStreamer::openVideoCamera()
{
   int deviceID = 1;
   int apiID = cv::CAP_ANY;
   cap.open(deviceID, apiID);

   double fps = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS);
   tUpdate.start(0);
}
```

and the output:

[image]

**Problems:**

1. Capture should not be made of the grids like these.
2. Capture should not be gray.

**Notes:**

1. I was using the same codes for another camera and it was working very well. I changed the camera and this happened.
2. I am using Linux - Ubuntu (18.04) and I think I installed all the necessary drivers. Camera is working fine in the app (Tcam-Capture)

****Update:** I looked the details on the Tcam app and noticed that it uses GRBG format. So I think I should format the QImage to GRBG, instead of RGB32. But there is no such thing as Format_Bayer or sth. So how can I fix this problem?**

3. I am working on the QT Creater.
4. Camera Model: DFM 27UR0135-ML - USB 3.0 color board camera

Comment: please show the code from the camera grabbing to the creation of the _corrupted_ image. Probably the camera outputs the frame in a different format and you're not dealing with it correctly.

Comment: updated. I added all the codes regarding the camera captures

Comment: ok, you're assuming that the output of your camera is always RGB888, but the doc of your camera says that it can output Y800, Y16 or RGB32. You need to take care of this while creating the QImage, or setup the camera to output what you want

Comment: Thank you for the important detail. So, there is no such thing as Format_Y800 or Y16. plus, Format_RGB32 did not help with correcting the colors. "Setup the camera to output what you want" How can I do this? The cap.set commands are listed here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d And I could not find a proper way to find an exact format that matches with the mentioned formats.

Comment: @Miki OpenCV's VideoCapture by default returns BGR888 data. it automatically converts from whatever the camera emits. **if** that happened to fail because the camera returns an unknown format, there are ways to request the untouched data from OpenCV. I don't see that done here. -- additionally, there is probably an issue in the adaptation from OpenCV data to something that Qt can display... to verify, use `imshow` or `imwrite`. _assuming_ the correct conversion from Mat to QImage is a mistake.